# How to connect to gmail using JavaMail over imap protocol?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I want to get the latest mail sent to my email address but my code is failing to connect to my Gmail account.

This is my code that used to work one month ago:

```java
        Properties props = new Properties();
        MailSSLSocketFactory sf = new MailSSLSocketFactory();
        sf.setTrustAllHosts(true);
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.imap.ssl.trust", "*");
        props.put("mail.imap.ssl.socketFactory", sf);
        Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props);
        mailSession.setDebug(true);
        Store mailStore = mailSession.getStore("imap");
        mailStore.connect("imap.gmail.com", email, emailPassword);
        Folder inbox = mailStore.getFolder("INBOX");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
```

Expected result: It actually connects to my Gmail account.

Actual result: This is the error logs.

```
mailStore.connect("imap.gmail.com", email, emailPassword); //This line throws the error



Exception in thread "main" com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't 
connect to host, port: imap.gmail.com, 993; timeout -1;
nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:740)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
at AccountUnlocker.getHTMLFromEmail(AccountUnlocker.java:322)
at AccountUnlocker.unlock(AccountUnlocker.java:124)
at Main.main(Main.java:6)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:359)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:238)
at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:134)
at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:131)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.newIMAPProtocol(IMAPStore.java:763)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:698)
... 5 more
```

Edit: I've allowed imap connections to my gmail, also set the Allow less secure apps to true.

Edit2: SOLVED! Temporarily disabling Avast fixed it for me!

Comment: Have you tried the same code with "Access for less secure apps" activated? ( https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1 )

Comment: Please provide the error logs on here.

Comment: Mokuyobi: Yes I've enabled imap acess and set allow less secure apps to true.

Comment: J_D: Added them on here!

Comment: GMail's IMAP is known to be problematic.

Comment: Gmail instructions are in the [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#gmail), along with [tips for debugging connection problems](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#condebug).  Most likely there's an anit-virus or proxy preventing you from connecting directly.  Finally, note that you can simplify your code by removing the explicit use of the socket factory; the property settings have the same effect.